# Badge earned info overflows out of div on Stack Overflow 'User Activity' page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

If you go to your user profile on Stack Overflow (and presumably other SE pages) after earning a new badge the box that tells you about it has out of bounds content:

[image: Overflowing content]

As you can see, the text at the bottom is cut off.

Here is my system information:

```
Chrome 69
Windows 10
1920x1080
```

And for clarity, this is the URL I am seeing this on - while logged in as that user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/635522/bananaapple

If there's anything else you need to know let me know :-)